# Using Census Bulk Geocoder with python requests library

Tags: python, python-requests, geocoding, census

I am experimenting with the census bulk geocode API [documentation](http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/Geocoding_Services_API.pdf)

The following curl command works:

```
curl --form addressFile=@Addresses.csv --form benchmark=9 http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/locations/addressbatch --output geocoderesult.csv
```

But when I attempt to port this to python requests:

```
url = 'http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/geographies/addressbatch'
payload = {'benchmark':9}
files = {'addressFile': ('Addresses.csv', open('Addresses.csv', 'rb'), 'text/csv')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, data = payload)
print r.text
```

I am apparently not sending a well formed request and only receiving "There was an internal error" in response. Any idea what I am doing wrong in forming this request?

Comment: Turns out working on the same thing at the same time.  Just tried a quick cut and paste with your code and my csv, and it's returning a `status_code` of  `200`.  Might be a data problem in your CSV- check your data by uploading it here: http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/locations/addressbatch?form and see if it works there.

Comment: It was always returning a `statuscode` of `200`, but if you inspect the response it still contains "There was an internal error.  I've verified the csv is valid via submitting it through the curl example above. I'm thinking I just don't have the request formatted correctly yet to match the curl example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it! Turns out that the geographies request type required some parameters that the locations type did not. Working solution:

```
url = 'http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/geographies/addressbatch'
payload = {'benchmark':'Public_AR_Current','vintage':'ACS2013_Current'}
files = {'addressFile': ('Addresses.csv', open('Addresses.csv', 'rb'), 'text/csv')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, data = payload)
print r.text
```

Comment: Does this still work for you these days? I'm getting SSL handshake errors. If you had any advice, it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: @vikjam - Doesn't work for me now. If you have a solution, please share.

Answer (score 2):

May be this is a simpler way to do the same thing.

## You will get a clean output in pandas dataframe :)

```
# pip install censusgeocode    

import censusgeocode
import pandas as pd

cg = censusgeocode.CensusGeocode(benchmark='Public_AR_Census2010',vintage='Census2010_Census2010')
k = cg.addressbatch('D:\WORK\Addresses.csv')

# Bonus
# Get clean output in Dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame(k, columns=k[0].keys())

# PS: I tried with 9990 records in single batch
```

---

Reference:

https://pypi.org/project/censusgeocode/

https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/benchmarks

https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/vintages?form

https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/geographies/addressbatch?form

Answer (score 1):

Works great. Today I just used the code shown below.

```
url = 'https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/locations/addressbatch'
payload = {'benchmark':'Public_AR_Current','vintage':'ACS2013_Current'}
files = {'addressFile': ('19067.csv', open('19067.csv', 'rb'), 'text/csv')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, data = payload)
```